# Why does my angular routing shows blank page?

Tags: angular, routes

app-module
[enter image description here][1]
app-routing
[enter image description here][2]
browser
[enter image description here][3]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSfRA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKcsw.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUO2X.png

Comment: Can't any images you've placed into the question. Please share how routes are setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using router outlet in html?

> < router-outlet ></ router-outlet >

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your *.component.html where you want your routed components to be displayed.

Also double check if you're importing RouterModule in your `app-module.ts` or `app-routing.module.ts` (depending where are your routes set up)

Answer (score 0):

Think you have not imported the router module .Try importing routermodule to your app module.ts and use the < router-outlet ></ router-outlet > in your html page .Think you have not imported the router module